# iOS: CollectionView like date picker scrolling effect

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want a list in which 2nd item of list is a bit zoomed and highlighted and when i scroll that cell/item will get little smaller and next item becomes highlighted and zoomed. More like the date picker scrolling effect but with custom cells.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library there is a zooming effect for each collection cell.

https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSPagerView

You can use this type for zooming effect.

```
pagerView.transformer = FSPagerViewTransformer(type: .zoomout)
```

Answer (score 1):

1 way according to me is:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell : LandingCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "yourCellName", for: indexPath)
        if indexPath.item == 1 {
//zoom code u can do it by increase the cell height and increase the font size
}

    return cell
}
```

// same do it with size of cell

Comment: 2nd way is using the FSpagerView.